# Разделение текста по столбцам в EXCEL

Tags: excel

Есть столбец в excel, необходима формула: Если символов в ячейке больше 30, то остальные символы должны быть перенесены во второй столбец.

Comment: и в чем затруднения, `ЕСЛИ, ДЛСТР, ПСТР` ?

Comment: Опять контекстная реклама... Слова можно рвать?

Comment: Можно рвать....

Comment: Тогда просто. Выше предложены функции. Пробуйте

Comment: Ну спасибо, тогда зачем я здесь? Логика железная у вас

Comment: Ну, как? Подсказку получили. Можно же открыть справку и самостоятельно попытаться сделать? А не получилось, тогда с вопросом...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно обойтись без формулы:

1. Выделяете колонку, которую хотите разбить
2. Идете во вкладку Data, нажимаете "Text to columns"
3. В визарде выбираете "Fixed width" и жмете Next
4. Откручиваете бегунок на нужную дину
5. Жмете Finish

Comment: так надо остальные, а не первые

Comment: Все правильно. Надо 30 + остаток (если он есть), а не остаток=30

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

Первая часть:

```
=ЛЕВБ(A2;30)
```

Вторая часть:

```
=ПСТР(A2;31;999)
```

Могут остаться слева или справа пробелы. От них можно избавиться с помощью

```
=СЖПРОБЕЛЫ(...)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

OldHuman, в ячейке А1 Ваш текст; в ячейку А2 и А3 соответственно вставьте формулы: =ЛЕВСИМВ(A1;30)  и =ПРАВСИМВ(A1;ДЛСТР(A1)-30)

Comment: Спасибо большое!